# How to solve "illegal character" error when saving Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add a custom function to a Google Spreadsheet.  I looked at the tutorial for Google Spreadsheet custom function while it was clear insofar as it went, and i think I followed it, I am having problems that seem to be so basic I cant form the right query to find the answer.

I went into the Google Spreadsheet in question, opened up script manager, select NEW, Google Spreadsheet and it opens a window "Untitled Progject" with a "code.gs" file with 2 functions already in it.  I dont know why they are there and presume that I just append mine to the end which I did as follows:

The line beginning "var WdName" is line 38 where it says there is an illegal character

```
 /**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the
 * values for each row.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

function DAYNAME(inNum) {
  // Function to convert from integers to Week Day names
  var wdName=“NONE”;     // this will hold the answer  
  if (typeof inNum != "number") {  // check to make sure input is a number
    throw "input must be a number";  // throw an exception with the error message
  }
    if (inNum == 1) {
    wdName=“Sunday”;
}
    if (inNum == 2) {
    wdName=“Monday”;
}
    if (inNum == 3) {
    wdName=“Tuesday”;
}
    if (inNum == 4) {
    wdName=“Wednesday”;
}
    if (inNum == 5) {
    wdName=“Thursday”;
}
    if (inNum == 6) {
    wdName=“Friday”;
}
    if (inNum == 7) {
    wdName=“Saturday”;
}

  return wdName;  // return the answer to the cell which has the formula
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.  I did try searching in this forum and elsewhere and while I suspect there is an answer there, I couldnt find it.

Thanks

Comment: When you select a "script type", the editor helps you out by providing some example code - in this case, simple functions that would manipulate a spreadsheet. You can always choose "blank script" - which isn't quite blank, since it has an empty function in it, but close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the quotes look a invalid character for Apps Script editor, you only need to change to solve the other double quote or single quote.

```
var wdName=“NONE”; // change to -> var wdName="NONE";
```

The quotes in the following line (39) is valid: `if (typeof inNum != "number")`

It should change all quotes that you see with this, there are several in the code:

```
...
wdName=“Sunday”; // change to -> var wdName="Sunday";
...
wdName=“Monday”; // change to -> var wdName="Monday";
...
```

Comment: That totally solved the problem. Thanks!!  I probably should have used some sort of programming-oriented text editor instead of LibreOffice and saving as a .txt.  I had no idea that it would save more than one kind of double quote.